# Trying to get icu4c version 64 working with PHP 5.6 on Mac Catalina

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I just got handed a big project running Symfony 3.4, and PHP 5.6, that I'm trying to get working on my "new" Mac Catalina (just purchased and installed, not upgraded from a previous macOS version), and I've gotten things working up to a certain point:

```
our-symfony-3-project $ bin/console server:start
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.64.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@5.6/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      bin/console server:start
```

I was able to fix a previous similar error with needing openssl 1.0.0 (I had to compile it from source using Homebrew then link it), and I think the solution is the same here, but it appears that I need to find the library or repo or download for icu4c version 64 (not sure I'm reading this right) to get `brew extract` to install it (it won't any other way), or figure out how to compile it and manually get it working for PHP 5.6, and I'm not finding the library I need apparently.

I've gone through pages and pages and probably a hundred command attempts trying to fix this error... and so far the recommendations have either been outdated (due to macOS/brew changes), or just didn't work.

I'd like to know where I can find the appropriate file/download/repo to just be able to install or compile this through brew or otherwise. PS: I know we shouldn't be using old versions but I just got this job and the company will not upgrade for a while.

Comment: Would it be easier to use PHP in Docker?

Comment: @halfer I don't know, I've used Docker with pre-installed setups, but I haven't set up a new PHP container myself... going through the tutorials and recommendations, it got very complicated and RAM-heavy with simple things like the example-voting-app, and I don't know whether that would be more feasible than trying to get PHP 5.6 working on my Mac like the devs before me did (though they didn't start with a new Mac Catalina install). So... it seems easier to just fix the PHP 5.6 errors here... but I'm not sure. It seems like I need libicui18n.64.dylib but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I personally think that hunting down specific missing binaries is a rather esoteric task, so you may find it hard to get help on that specifically. If you are still waiting, might it be worth [trying Docker PHP](https://prototype.php.net/versions/5.6/install/docker) in parallel and having a horse-race between the two solutions? (With the choices on offer here, I'd go with `5.6-apache-stretch` for simplicity)? I wonder if the PHP Dockerfile would not need to be very complex.

Comment: FWIW, I think Docker is a win anyway, since all devs can make use of it when working on the same repo. I would not start a new PHP project today without it.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that MAMP Pro has PHP 5.6 built in and runs, but now I'm having trouble getting composer to work with it as well as our repos... so many complications. Anyway, it sounds like Docker is the ultimate solution for any PHP project or version. I'm hoping it won't suddenly deprecate things like Homebrew and macOS has and send me back down the same path looking for old binaries. I just had to post the original question out of exhaustion.

Comment: PHP + Docker on Mac wouldn't use Homebrew - it is essentially a Linux machine running on a largely hidden VirtualBox + Ubuntu virtual machine. You can use any Linux distro in Docker that still has 5.6 available, and when distro support for that finally gives up, you can download a copy of the 5.6 source code and compile it yourself (I did this for 5.4 some while back).

Comment: Note that I got the repo running using `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`... why that worked I'm not sure, but it's currently running under PHP 5.6 on MAMP Pro 6.3.2 if this ends up mattering to anyone. I'll likely try to get Docker containers for these old PHP versions that I can then use as templates for old repos like this.

Comment: @halfer I wasn't saying that Docker would use or require Homebrew for a PHP 5.6 container (I wouldn't make a macOS container anyway, I'd use Linux)... I was saying that I hope something with Docker wouldn't suddenly deprecate or remove a dependency somewhere like Homebrew has with many PHP 5.6 required libraries, which would require me hunting down the required library download and compiling it manually somewhere. Maybe that's not a concern on Docker, I don't know yet, but I know that I'll have to rely on images or dependencies that are still hosted somewhere until I get a container set up.

Comment: Yeah, they are (or should be) completely unrelated. Docker is an application that runs on a Mac, and anything that goes into it (PHP) is completely isolated from the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this by saying that I got the repo to work on a PHP 5.6 host using MAMP Pro (and Apache, not that that's relevant)... which already had the required libraries in question.

I went through the docs on the trial version (version 6.3.2):

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Settings/Hosts/General/

However, unlike Homebrew, switching PHP versions across hosts in MAMP Pro doesn't overwrite PHP symlinks like `brew unlink` and `brew link` does, I have to still edit my .zshrc file aliases and my PATH to have things like `php` (or `pecl` or `pear` etc) point to the MAMP Pro PHP version folders to get them to work correctly with the repos, as well as with `composer` (which runs the `php` command). Even MAMP's documentation says to modify the files yourself...

I can't tell yet if this difficulty is just natural to having multiple hosts with different PHP versions configured, as I could see how multiple variations running at the same time could conflict if they're using the same system files (like /usr/local files)... which sound like system software dependencies, and I don't know that these dependencies could be relegated to their own host folders (like /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.40 folders), or maybe I just missed something somewhere. I'll update this answer if I learn better what to do here, or will add another answer if I find a way to do them using Homebrew better.